# How to Merge two Mysql Databases with same structure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures

Having two MySql databases with same structure but different entries (data). No issue of primary key at all.

Kindly help me how I can merge two databses?

Comment: why don't you use phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use phpMyAdmin ( Install if you still don't use it )
2. Go to the current database
3. click import and import the other database

**Possible Issues :**

- The max file upload size in phpmyadmin may be 2MB.To solve this increase the maximum file upload size  php.ini

Comment here if you have any issues

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not quite clear, but if all you want is to add all the data from DB `B` to DB `A`, then mysqladmin is your friend:

```
mysqldump -n -t -u userB --password=*** dbB | mysql -u userA --password=*** dbA
```